# Как настроить автоматическое форматирование кода в vs.code?

Tags: visual-studio-code

Чтобы не нажимать каждый раз SHIFT+ALT+F. А при редактировании кода он сам автоматически форматировался.
У меня уже такое было, но у vscode слетели настройки и плагины, забыл как настроить.

Answer (score 0):

Зайдите в настройки

```
      Settings->

        editor.formatOnType - Format после ввода строки
        editor.formatOnSave - Format на сохранении
        editor.formatOnPaste - Format на вставку.
```

Ставите галочку когда нужно форматировать